# Does a text file have an output limit?

Tags: powershell

I have 2 scripts

`script1.ps1` retrieves database/cube connections from the servers. 
script2.ps1 calls script1

> script2:

```
$logfile = ".\log.txt"

& ".\script1.ps1" -ViewConnection "$cinput" -OutVariable xprtOut | Format-Table -Wrap | tee $logfile -Append
```

the interesting thing i noticed is i get about 138 connections retrieved and displayed on the console, but only up to 78 connections are printed to the log file.

log file:

[image: log]

console:

[image: console]

why does it truncate/dont print the rest of the connections in the logfile?
very strange...

Comment: Remove `Format-Table -Wrap` (or move it to the _end_ of the pipeline, after `tee`)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen wow youre right! by moving it to the end it printed the rest now. but why is that?

Comment: @Cataster I think it's because the `-wrap` will remove anything that exceeds a certain width in order to make the table nice

Comment: @techguy1029 just tried it with removing -wrap. it printed all to the text file. interesting

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen since it worked based on your suggestion/techguy's, can you post an answer with explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't print formatted output to file!

The `Format-*` cmdlets format the output based on *the current screen buffer* and the resulting objects are filled with metadata that makes no sense when read back from a file.

Move `| Format-Table -Wrap` to the end of the pipeline, *after* `Tee-Object` has written to disk:

```
& ".\script1.ps1" -ViewConnection "$cinput" -OutVariable xprtOut | tee $logfile -Append | Format-Table -Wrap
```